# Drawing chart with color lines

Tags: c#, charts, drawing

I'm using chart component in C# WinForms application. I can draw many series, but all lines are in the same color. When in chart I have just one line then color appears.

Below is the code I use to set new point for specific series

```
 private void SetChart(string title, double x, double y)
    {
        //if (y > 1000) return;
        if (this.chart.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.chart.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    chart.Series[title].Points.AddXY(x, y);
                    chart.Update();
                }
                catch
                {
                    chart.Series.Add(title);
                    chart.Series[title].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    chart.Series[title].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chart.Series[title].Points.AddXY(x, y);
                    chart.Update();
                }
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                chart.Series[title].Points.AddXY(x, y);
                chart.Update();
            }
            catch
            {
                chart.Series.Add(title);
                chart.Series[title].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
                chart.Series[title].Points.AddXY(x, y);
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = LearnByError.Internazional.Resource.Inst.Get("r57");
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = LearnByError.Internazional.Resource.Inst.Get("r56");
                chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                chart.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is used in the way presented below, which allowes me to draw:

```
 foreach (var weights in lr.ResultWeights)
            {
                String name = LearnByError.Internazional.Resource.Inst.Get("r53") + trial.ToString();
                weightsList.Items.Add(name);
                for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
                {
                    weightsList.Items.Add(weights[i].ToString());
                }
                weightsList.Items.Add("");

                if (lr.Info.np == 0) throw new Exception(LearnByError.Internazional.Resource.Inst.Get("r54"));
                foreach (var rmse in lr.RMSE)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < rmse.Length; j++)
                    {
                        SetChart(name, j + 1, rmse[j]);                           
                    }
                }
                trial++;
            }
```

If someone had such problem I would be happy to find out...

And the image of chart
[image]

Comment: You can set a different color for each series and also for each datapoint. You just need to do it; instead you set the same color eavery time.

Answer (score 1):

If your `InvokeRequired` is false, you never set the color of the series. And, if `InvokeRequired` is true, you always set the color to red, rather than setting them all to different colors.

Comment: I removed checking InvokeRequired because I don't need it. I can see like it draws color lines and after drawing end all lines are changed to gray color. Strange. I haven't found no more code asociated with chart. Any ideas?